# Convert month columns to dates

Tags: r, dataframe

I have this data frame that gives values by months.

| initial value | release date | month_1 value | month_2 value | month_3 value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 1/1/2024 | 99 | 94 | 90 |
| 50 | 1/1/2025 | 40 | 30 | 10 |

I want to expand the data frame to convert it to dates. How do I do this?

| initial value | release date | 1/1/2024 | 2/1/2024 | 3/1/2024 | ... | 1/1/2025 | 2/1/2025 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 1/1/2024 | 99 | 94 | 90 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 50 | 1/1/2025 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 40 | 30 |

This is in MM/DD/YYYY format

Answer (score 1):

Here's a tidyverse pipe:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)     # pivot_*
library(lubridate) # %m+%
quux |>
  pivot_longer(cols = -c(`initial value`, `release date`)) |>
  mutate(
    name = as.Date(`release date`, format = "%m/%d/%Y") %m+% months(as.integer(sub(".*_([0-9]+) .*", "\\1", name)) - 1L),
    name = format(name, "%m/%d/%Y")
  ) |>
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c(`initial value`, `release date`))
# # A tibble: 2 × 8
#   `initial value` `release date` `01/01/2024` `02/01/2024` `03/01/2024` `01/01/2025` `02/01/2025` `03/01/2025`
#             <int> <chr>                 <int>        <int>        <int>        <int>        <int>        <int>
# 1             100 1/1/2024                 99           94           90           NA           NA           NA
# 2              50 1/1/2025                 NA           NA           NA           40           30           10
```

(Not sure why you want `2024` date columns for the 2025 row. Also, except for *reporting* and for some cross-month comparisons, I generally recommend against having "data"-like things as column names, regardless of whether they are standard R names.)

---

Data

```r
quux <- structure(list("initial value" = c(100L, 50L), "release date" = c("1/1/2024", "1/1/2025"), "month_1 value" = c(99L, 40L), "month_2 value" = c(94L, 30L), "month_3 value" = c(90L, 10L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```